# Phonegap, google maps blank screen

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps, cordova

I work in a phonegap project. When insert map of Google in a div tag show the logo and controls to the map, but not show the map, the page is blank.

I include a jquery file, library Google Maps from *.googleapis.com o *.maps.google.com.

Test the code In a browser (safari, chrome, ie) works fine but in the xcode simulator and my iphone is blank screen with the logos of Google.

Any idea?

Comment: Can you post the code that you are using?

Comment: do you set  <access origin="*" /> on config.xml

Comment: in the config.xml file already exists <access origin="*" />. The ajax requests to remote server work correctly. Attached image of it appears on my iphone... [link]http://www.subirimagenes.net/i/13090911222352748.png

Comment: The code works correctly because in the desktop browser works fine.

Comment: have you any suggestion, please?

Comment: do you solved this issue? @SergioGarrido

Comment: no, I have the same problem @m1crdy

Comment: please, any suggestion??